# How to load data into spark from a remote HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

Our data is stored at a remote Hadoop Cluster, but for doing some PoC I need to run spark application locally on my machine. How can I load data from that remote HDFS?

Comment: For PoC just copy data from HDFS to your computer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can [configure spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#custom-hadoophive-configuration) to access any hadoop instance you have access to.(Ports open, nodes reachable)

> Custom Hadoop/Hive Configuration
>
> If your Spark application is interacting with Hadoop, Hive, or both, there are probably Hadoop/Hive
> configuration files in Spark’s classpath.
>
> Multiple running applications might require different Hadoop/Hive
> client side configurations. You can copy and modify hdfs-site.xml,
> core-site.xml, yarn-site.xml, hive-site.xml in Spark’s classpath for
> each application. In a Spark cluster running on YARN, these
> configuration files are set cluster-wide, and cannot safely be changed
> by the application.

As you want to access HDFS you need: hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml from your cluster you are trying to access.

Comment: Technically, the XML files aren't needed. You can modify the hadoopConfiguration / SparkSession at runtime

Comment: 100% true, just more convenient to use them to avoid typos. But you are correct they are not required.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone, who wants to access remote HDFS from Spark Java app, here is steps.

Firstly, you need to add --conf key to your run command. Depends on Spark version:

- (Spark 1.x-2.1)
  spark.yarn.access.namenodes=hdfs://clusterA,hdfs://clusterB
- (Spark 2.2+) spark.yarn.access.hadoopFileSystems=hdfs://clusterA,hdfs://clusterB

Secondly, when you creating Spark’s Java context, add that:

```
javaSparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().addResource(new Path("core-site-clusterB.xml"));
javaSparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().addResource(new Path("hdfs-site-clusterB.xml"));
```

If you facing this exception:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: clusterB

then try to put full namenode address of your remote HDFS with port (instead of hdfs/cluster short name) to --conf into your running command.

More details in my article: [https://mchesnavsky.tech/spark-java-access-remote-hdfs](https://mchesnavsky.tech/spark-java-access-remote-hdfs/).